# For-loop order (with asynchronous function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop, request

I have this code :

```
exports.formatDepArrTables = function(jsonReturn, type, placeName, callback) {
    let toSend = "";

    if (type == 'departure') {
        for (let j = 0; j < jsonReturn.departures.length; j++) {
            console.log("DEPARTURES LOOP j = " + j + "/" + jsonReturn.departures.length);

            if(currentDeparture.display_informations.links[0] === undefined) {
                toSend += ""; // setting some string informations
            }
            else {
                let oceTrainId = ""; // random number given by a json
                _this.getDisruptionFromDisruptionId(oceTrainId, function(data) {
                    for(let i = 0; i < data.disruptions[0].impacted_objects[0].impacted_stops.length; i++) {
                        if(currentImpactedStop.stop_point.label == placeName) {
                            toSend += "string";
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        console.log("End of the first loop");
        return callback(toSend);

    } else if (type == 'arrival') {
        // copy&paste
    } else {
        throw new Error("not defined");
    }
};
```

When I run this code (I use NodeJS), it makes 1/10, 2/10... from the first loop but it didn't iterate the second loop on the 1st iteration of the first loop (and it shows "End of the first loop" and starts the second loop).

`getDisruptionFromDisruptionId` is a custom method which makes a request (with 'request' NodeJS module) on an API.

Of course, I need to have informations given by `getDisruptionFromDisruptionId` to run my next loop...

Parent function of this code part is returning a callback that needs to be "filled" at the end of the both two loops.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `request` is async, function, you need to add async / await to your code or use recursion

Comment: Adding async/await worked like a charm for now! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` is async function, you need to add async / await to your code or use recursion